# SSRS DateTime format the paramaters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have two datetime parameters in my report (from date and to date).

Cannot seem to get the formatting to work though.

The default for FromDate should be yesterday (19/01/2015 00:00:00) and the ToDate should be yesterday (19/01/2015 23:59:59)

Comment: What is the format that you want for the dates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the parameter type of both parameters to `Text` and use the following expressions to set the values:

```
= FormatDateTime("01/19/2015 00:00:00") <---- For 'From Date`
= FormatDateTime("01/19/2015 23:59:59") <---- For 'To Date`
```

`dd/mm/yyyy` format seems to throw an error while `mm/dd/yyyy` doesn't.

The above is for hardcoded vales. Adding a script for dynamic in sometime.

**EDIT**

Below is the solution to meet your requirement:

Keep your parameter type as `Date/Time` and use the following expressions to set the default value

```
ENDDATE = 

=dateadd(
        dateinterval.Second, 
        -1, 
        CDate(today)
        )

STARTDATE= 

=dateadd(
        dateinterval.Day, 
        -1, 
        CDate(today)
        )
```

Comment: I was thinking that but then the calendar control will not show up if I do that.

Comment: I think it will still give the 12 hour format but still good for the OP requirement